# Compute Riemannian metric.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ given by
$$ \varphi(x_{1}, x_{2}) = (x_{1}, 2x_{1}, x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}) $$
and consider the surface $S = \varphi(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, so $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to S$ is a global parametrization of $S$. We now consider an scalar product $ \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\varphi(0,0)} $ on the tangent plane $T_{\varphi(0,0)} S$, so the basis of $T_{\varphi(0,0)} S$ given by the parametrization is an orthonormal basis. Now let $\phi_{(a, b)}: S \to S$ the mapping given by
$$ \phi_{(a, b)} (\varphi(x_{1}, x_{2})) = \varphi(x_{1} + a, x_{2} + b),$$
so it's clear that $\phi_{(a, b)}$ is a diffeomorphism of $S$. We now define the scalar product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\varphi(a, b)}$ on $T_{\varphi(a, b)} S$ such that the linear mapping $\text{d} \phi_{(a, b)}(0, 0): T_{\varphi(0,0)} S \to T_{\varphi(a, b)}$ is a linear isometry. Now let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the Riemannian metric defined this way.

I am asked to compute the coefficients $g_{ij}$ of this metric. As the differential $ \text{d}\phi_{(a, b)}(0,0)$ is the identity mapping, the coefficients of this metric are given by the Kronecker delta $g_{ij} = \delta_{i}^{j}$, am I right?

Comment: as defined, in local coordinates, the metric is just the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so yes, in these coordinates it coordinates are given by the Kronecker $\delta $ function. Or said in a different way: $\varphi (\mathbb{R}^2)$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @Masacroso thanks! Thought I was missing something, as the Riemannian structure is so trivial and I am also asked to compute Christoffel symbols (all of them are zero), geodesics equations (lines in the coordinate chart) and sectional curvatures...